# If else statement - value greater or less than.. confused

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a very simple statement that checks whether a value is less than the other, but it does not work, anyone who can check it quickly? Have seen me completely blind to this.

```
$balance = $wallet->balance(); //3000
$loan = $wallet->loan(); // 5000
if (!$balance < $loan) { //Should be pretty straight forward...
    $wallet->updateBalance(Session::get('user'),$balance - 1000);
    $wallet->updateLoan(Session::get('user'),$loan - 1000);
    Redirect::to('bank.php');
} else {
    Redirect::to('bank.php');
}
```

When I run this code it removes 1000 regardless if $balance is less. If I remove the exclamation mark it redirects right away, as it should.

I really do not understand what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the complete script:

```
    <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if (Input::exists('get')) {

    if (Input::get('borrow')) {
        $wallet = new Wallet;
        if ($wallet->get(Session::get('user'))) {
            $balance = $wallet->balance();
            $loan = $wallet->loan();
            $wallet->updateBalance(Session::get('user'),$balance + 1000);
            $wallet->updateLoan(Session::get('user'),$loan + 1000);
            Redirect::to('bank.php');
        }

    } else if (Input::get('repay')) {
        $wallet = new Wallet;
        if ($wallet->get(Session::get('user'))) {
            $balance = $wallet->balance();
            $loan = $wallet->loan();
            if ($balance < $loan) {
                $wallet->updateBalance(Session::get('user'),$balance - 1000);
                $wallet->updateLoan(Session::get('user'),$loan - 1000);
                Redirect::to('bank.php');
            } else {
                Redirect::to('bank.php');
            }

        }
    } else {
        Redirect::to('bank.php');
    }

} else {
    Redirect::to('bank.php');
}
```

All redirects are temporary .. Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `if (!($balance < $loan))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is with how operators are being applied in your if condition. Instead of `if (!$balance < $loan)`, try `if (!($balance < $loan))` or `if ($balance >= $loan)`

The problem is partly because of how PHP represents types internally, and partly because of operator precedence. The negation operator is being applied first. Because bools are represented by integers in PHP, the result of this expression is `FALSE`, which is equivalent to `0`.

Comment: The opposite of `!(a<b)` would be `a>=b`.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I cant believe i didnt see that one.